# Leaflet Awesome-Markers (Adding Numbers)

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, font-awesome, markers

I am using the [Leaflet.Awesome-Markers](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers) plugin with [LeafletJS](http://leafletjs.com/).

I have implemented it correctly, however now I'd like to be able to use numbers from 0 - 9 to represent markers.

Here's a JS Fiddle implementation to show how the plugin behaves.

http://jsfiddle.net/fulvio/VPzu4/200/

The plugin allows the use of font-awesome icons and glyph icons (both of course, do not offer any 0 - 9 numbers as icons. *argh*!)

- http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons
- http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/

The documentation mentions the ability to use `extraClasses` and I was wondering whether anyone could point me in the right direction as to how to leverage from this in order to display numbers rather than icons or whether there is simply another way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the comment **@Can**.

The author of awesome-markers got another tree where he added exactly what you are looking for [awesome-markers with numbers/letters](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers/tree/6dd41539428caa28f75b30fa2cd8dcba2c202a86/dist) be sure to grab the unminified JS.

Comment: The author of awesome-markers got another tree where he added exactly what you are looking for [awesome-markers with numbers/letters](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers/tree/6dd41539428caa28f75b30fa2cd8dcba2c202a86/dist) be sure to grab the unminified JS

Comment: My fault, haven't tried it before commenting. Don't know why but couldn't get it working. So I'm using rockXrock's solution, and it works like a charm, thanks for that

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of using the Awesome-Markers plugin, you could follow this article on creating numbered markers in Leaflet:

http://blog.charliecroom.com/index.php/web/numbered-markers-in-leaflet

The associated Gist is here:

https://gist.github.com/comp615/2288108

An simple example of how this would work is as follows:

```
// The text could also be letters instead of numbers if that's more appropriate
var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(0, 0), {
    icon:   new L.NumberedDivIcon({number: '1'})
});
```

Comment: Careful when using this solution. Its licensed under "Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike 3.0 United States License." and thus not usable in a commercial context.

Answer (score 37):

I have tried Numbered Markers plugin, but it icon is not pretty as other Awesome Markers, and make page layout style inconsistent, so I made small changes in Awesome-Markers plugin to make it support numbers. It is very simple.

1. this is Numbered Markers plugin effect, if you like it please skip my answer. [image]
2. change leaflet.awesome-markers.js line 2, add html:""

   ```
   L.AwesomeMarkers.Icon = L.Icon.extend({
   options: {
       iconSize: [35, 45],
       iconAnchor:   [17, 42],
       popupAnchor: [1, -32],
       shadowAnchor: [10, 12],
       shadowSize: [36, 16],
       className: 'awesome-marker',
       prefix: 'glyphicon',
       spinClass: 'fa-spin',
       extraClasses: '',
       icon: 'home',
       markerColor: 'blue',
       iconColor: 'white',
       html : ""
   },
   ```
3. change leaflet.awesome-markers.js line 80,

   ```
   return "<i " + iconColorStyle + "class='" + options.extraClasses + " " 
   + options.prefix + " " + iconClass + " " + iconSpinClass + " " 
   + iconColorClass + "'>" + options.html + "</i>";
   ```
4. when creating icon, call like before

   ```
   var jobMarkerIcon = L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({
   icon: '',
   markerColor: 'darkblue',
   prefix: 'fa',
   html: (i+1)
   });
   ```
5. comment out line 45 and 47.
6. the result is like below screenshot. [image]
7. code changes diff shows below. [image]

Comment: where to download with Numbered Markers plugin. i need full instruction to work with. thanks

Comment: and to plot point (if like me you didn't know about awesome markers in the first place): L.marker([50,70], {icon: jobMarkerIcon}).addTo(map);

Comment: Note : the recent version of awesome-markers allows to do this with the text option. There is no need to do this walkthrough anymore.

Answer (score 7):

Another strategy is to use the [Leaflet.ExtraMarkers plugin](https://github.com/coryasilva/Leaflet.ExtraMarkers)

Code the numeric marker with these options:

```
var numMarker = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
icon: 'fa-number',
number: 12,
markerColor: 'blue'
});
L.marker([41.77, -72.69], {icon: numMarker}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the font-awesome, a fairly simple solution presented here:
[Simple Numbered Markers](https://web.archive.org/web/20141128173521/https://dotscrapbook.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/simple-numbered-markers-with-leaflet-js/)
it doesn't need any extra library. It's already in leaflet. Just create a CSS class with icon image like this:

```
.number-icon
{
    background-image: url("images/number-marker-icon.png");
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;   
}
```

Then create icon like this:

```
var numberIcon = L.divIcon({
      className: "number-icon",
      shadowSize: [20, 30], // size of the shadow
      iconAnchor: [20, 40], 
      shadowAnchor: [4, 30],  // the same for the shadow
      popupAnchor: [0, -30],
      html: variable_containing_the_number        
});

var marker = new L.marker([lat, long],
{                               
    icon: numberIcon                               
});
```

Comment: As the link above is broken, [here is the archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20141128173521/https://dotscrapbook.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/simple-numbered-markers-with-leaflet-js/).